# Programming angles between points

Tags: iphone, math

I would like to program a small feature where the user touches the screen, and e.g. 2 arrows point towards the touch location.

If there is a touch location in the middle, near the bottom, how does one calculate the angle between these or the direction to it?

[image]

I want to get the angle between the source of the arrow, lets say it is a circle, and I want the angle to point from the edge of the circle to the touch location. I want to be able to know where in the circle the arrow should start from, in order to have the correct angle to the touch location.

Comment: So from two fixed points, you would like arrows to appear and point toward the touch location.  Have you been able to receive touch events  and coordinates from touchesBegan?  If so, then rendering those arrows should just involve pretty basic trig.

Answer (score 3):

To find the angle between a 90 deg angle and your point you can just use some basic trigonometry.

[image]

If you imagine a third point B at (x of touch, y of point), you'll end up with a right triangle. Then finding your angle is simple since tan(angle) = opposite side/adjacent side, or (xa - xb)/(yb - yt). So `angle = tan^-1((xa - xb)/(yb - yt))`.

Comment: For the actual code I would recommend using `atan2`, it takes the x difference and y difference as separate arguments so it handles special cases nicely.